# Jquery append - printing two times the same information

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

This must be a basic question but I can't get arround.
Why is the append method printing two times the same information into a div?

HTML:

```
<div class="error_display"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var errorlist = [];
    errorlist.length = 0;
    errorlist.push("Array test");
    for(var i = 0; i < errorlist.length; i++) {
        $('.error_display').append(errorlist[i]+"<br/>");       
    }
});
```

Comment: Check [http://jsfiddle.net/sXauN/](http://jsfiddle.net/sXauN/). above code prints information once only. May be ` $('.error_display')` is used somewhere else in the code for data append.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or plnkr?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `console.log(/* variable of interest */);` to monitor some of the conditions that you are watching for. You could also add in something to check if the line already exists if all else fails.